# Does git checkout really copy commit?

Tags: git

I have a development branch, this branch has these commits X, Y, Z. When I checkout a new feature (call FeatureX) from development branch, the commits in FeatureX are still X,Y,Z or are copied into X', Y', Z'?
Please help me!

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean by "are commits copied?". `git checkout` changes current file tree to the state of some commit, nothing is practically changed in the repository

Comment: I mean FeatureX will now have commits X, Y, Z. And are these X, Y, Z commits the commits of the development branch, or is it a copy of the old X, Y, Z development's commit?

Comment: I mean FeatureX will now have commits X, Y, Z, or FeatureX will have a copy of the old X, Y, Z development's commit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `git checkout` command copies the *files* out of a commit.  It must do so, because the files *in* a commit are not in a usable form.  But in this case you've asked a question whose answer is not going to help you much.  There's a much better set of questions to ask.

#### What is a Git repository?

A *repository* is, for the most part, a collection of commits.  There is a bit more to a repository though.  For instance, besides the commits, each repository has a collection of *names:* branch names, tag names, and other such names.

The *amount* more depends on the *kind* of repository:

- A so-called *bare* repository, as found on a server, mostly stops here.
- The kind of repository you'll use adds a *working tree*, which is where you will do your actual work, plus a bunch of other features needed for getting work done, recovering from mistakes, and so on.

While those are important, the *commits* are the keys here.  Branch names are important too, but only because they help us (and Git) *find* the commits we want to find.  So as a Git newbie, you need to understand what a commit is, and does for you.

#### What is a commit?

The commit is the main unit of storage in a Git repository.  It has the following features:

- Every commit is *numbered*.  The numbers aren't simple counting numbers, though: we don't have commit #1 followed by commit #2, then #3 and #4 and so on.  Instead, each number is unique but *looks entirely random* and is spelled funny, as a big [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) number.  Git calls these *hash IDs*.
- Every commit, once made, is completely and totally frozen for all time.
- Each commit stores two things:

  - It has a full snapshot of *all* of your files, as of whatever they had in them at the time you made the commit.  This is a sort of archive, like a tar or rar archive, of every file.

    Obviously this would take a ton of disk space, so Git *stores* these files in a special, read-only, Git-only, compressed and *de-duplicated* form.  That makes the files quite unusable to everything but Git itself (which is why `git checkout` has to copy the files out, to expand them into a usable version), but it means that if you make a million commits, but keep re-using your files, this takes almost no space at all—there's still just the one copy of each file, re-used across all the million commits.
  - Besides the stored files, each commit stores some *metadata:* some information about the commit itself.  This includes the name and email address of the person who made the commit, for instance.  It includes a date-and-time stamp, for *when* they made it.  (In fact, each commit has two of these, one for "author" and one for "committer"—which are often the same, making it pointless to bother with both, but it doesn't take much space, so nobody cares that much.)

There are more optional features, but we don't really need to care about that right now.  The one thing we *do* need to care about here, though, is a particular feature *in* the metadata, that is crucial to Git itself: **Each commit stores the hash ID(s) of some previous commit(s).**  Most commits store exactly one such hash ID; Git calls these *ordinary* commits.

#### Commits form chains, like strings of pearls

What this means—which is the key to your immediate question—is that **each commit "remembers" its parent commit**.  We can draw this, visually, by noting that some commit, with some hash ID—let's just call it `H` for `hash`—will have, stored in that commit, the hash ID of some *earlier* commit.

We say that the later, or *child*, commit, *points to* the earlier, or *parent* commit, and we can draw that pointer as an arrow coming out of the commit:

```
            <-H
```

If we call the earlier commit `G`—using the letter before `H`—and draw that in, we get:

```
        <-G <-H
```

Of course, `G` has its own parent, `F`, which has *its* own parent, and so on:

```
... <-F <-G <-H
```

This keeps going all the way back to the very first commit someone ever made.  *That* commit *can't* point backwards, so it just doesn't:

```
A--B--C--...--G--H
```

Commit `A`, the very first commit, is a *root commit*, and a non-empty repository has to have at least one of these.  (Git allows you to make more than one, but, well, let's not go there.)

There are two points I'll make here:

1. I've gotten lazy and stopped drawing in the arrows between commits, just using lines.  But remember that they *are* one-way arrows: Git can only really go *backwards*.
2. While I've used simple letters here and it's obvious that `H` is the *last* one, in a real repository, the actual hash IDs are these horrible, big ugly random-looking hexadecimal numbers, that no human can ever keep straight.

This second point is a big problem: *how do we find commit `H` easily?*  For *Git* to do it, we have to tell Git the actual hash ID of commit `H`.  We might have to write that down somewhere, on paper or a whiteboard, and type it in.

But, wait a minute, we have a *computer*.  Computers are good at this sort of memorizing!  Let's take the hash ID `H`, whatever it is, and "write it down" somewhere *on the computer*.  Let's store it in a file, or a database, or something.  Let's use an easy-to-remember (for us) **name** to hold the hash ID.

#### This is where branch names enter the picture

If we draw our commits like *this*, you can see how the branch name works:

```
...--G--H   <-- dev
```

The *branch name*—`dev` in our case here—holds the *real hash ID* of the *last* commit in the sequence.  That's commit `H`.  So commits up through and including `H` are "on" the branch.

When you add a *new* branch name, like `featureX`, we just have Git create a new file, or a new entry in a database of branch names, or whatever, and *save the same hash ID* in that name:

```
...--G--H   <-- dev, featureX
```

What this means is that the commits up through and including `H` are now on *both branches*.

If you're used to other version control systems, you might be objecting right now: *Wait, hold on, why are they on **both** branches?*  Other version control systems say that a commit is on *one* branch only.  Git isn't those other version control systems: in Git, any one commit can be on *any number* of branches.

The way Git commits work, we use a *branch name* to find the *last* one, and then work backwards from there.  So commit `H` is now the last commit on *both* branches.  Commit `H` points back to earlier commit `G`, too—in fact, since nothing about commit `H` can ever change, commit `H` points back to `G` *forever*—so if `H` is on both branches, `G` is also on both branches.

#### The special name `HEAD`

There are some more things to know here.  Try running `git status`.  Its first line is:

```
on branch dev
```

or:

```
on branch featureX
```

or whatever.  *How does Git know which branch we're "on", and what does this mean?*

I've already mentioned—twice in fact—that `git checkout` copies the files out of a commit, un-freezing and un-Git-ifying them in the process.  That gives us a set of files that we can actually use, i.e., work with / on.

The `git checkout` command *also* selects the branch we'll be "on", as `git status` will say.

The *way* it does this is to use a very special name, `HEAD`, which isn't a *branch* name at all.  (This name is so special that if it gets damaged, Git stops believing that a Git repository *is* a Git repository.  It's a kind of active file, too, so if your computer ever crashes or loses power while you're working in a repository, there's a chance that the `HEAD` file gets damaged.  Fortunately it's usually easy to recover from this case.)  What Git does with this name is "attach" it to a branch name, like this:

```
...--G--H   <-- dev (HEAD), featureX
```

This means we're `on branch dev`, as `git status` will say.  The `git checkout` command extracted all the files from `H`, and attached `HEAD` to the name `dev`.  So our *current branch* is now `dev` and our *current commit* is the one selected by the name `dev`, i.e., commit `H`.

If we run `git checkout featureX`, Git:

- removes the files that came out of `H`;
- moves `HEAD` to attach it to `featureX`; and
- puts in the files that come out of `H`.

Git actually notices that the first and last steps are redundant and doesn't bother doing them.  So the only real *change* is in our drawing:

```
...--G--H   <-- dev, featureX (HEAD)
```

But, let's look at what happens when we *make a new commit*.

#### Making a new commit

We'll skip over all the details *about* making a commit, including why you have to keep running `git add`.  We'll just note that when you run `git commit`, Git doesn't actually use the files in your *working tree*—the ones you get to see and work on—but instead uses some *pre-prepared, pre-de-duplicated copies*.  These are the files that go into the *new* commit.

The new commit is going to get some random-looking (albeit unique) hash ID, but we'll just call it commit `I`.  Git will:

- save up the snapshot;
- add our name and email address for metadata, with "now" as the date-and-time;
- set the *parent* for the new commit to be the *current hash ID `H`*; and
- write out the commit, which is what produces the real hash ID for new commit `I`.

If we draw just the commits themselves, new commit `I` will point back to existing commit `H`:

```
...--G--H
         \
          I
```

But—what about the *branch names?*  Here's the really sneaky trick.  Git now writes the new commit's hash ID into the *name to which `HEAD` is attached*.  Since our `HEAD` was—and still is—attached to the name `featureX`, the name `featureX` is the one that gets updated:

```
...--G--H   <-- dev
         \
          I   <-- featureX (HEAD)
```

Now, commits up through `H` are still on both branches, but *new* commit `I` is *only* on branch `featureX`.

If we now run `git checkout dev`, here's what happens in our drawing:

```
...--G--H   <-- dev (HEAD)
         \
          I   <-- featureX
```

and this time, Git removes the files that go with commit `I` and extracts the files that go with commit `H`.

#### `git log` works from here backwards

If we run `git log` now, with us back on `dev`, we *won't see commit `I` at all*.  The reason is simple: `git log` uses `HEAD` to find a branch name, then uses the branch name to find a commit.  That's the *first* commit that `git log` will show: in this case, commit `H`.

Then, `git log` will use the *parent* stored *in* commit `H` to move back to earlier commit `G`.  Git will show us the log message for `G`, and then use the metadata in `G` to move back to commit `F`.

Git *cannot* go forward, from `H` to `I`: commit `H` *does not point to commit `I`* because `H` was made before `I` existed.  Git had no idea what hash ID `I` would have in the future (because the hash ID is made up from every part of the commit, including the source snapshot and the date-and-time-stamp).

If we run `git log featureX`, though, or `git checkout featureX` and then `git log`, Git will *start* from commit `I` and work backwards.  This will show us `H` and `G` and `F` too.  Those commits are, after all, on both branches.

#### What to remember

There is a lot of stuff to remember about Git.  It's a big program suite, with a lot of commands, and a lot of fancy abilities and so on.  But for now, you've learned:

- A repository is all about the *commits*.  The commits hold snapshots and metadata, and Git finds them by their random-looking hash IDs.
- Git *can* find the commits by names: branch names, mainly, but also other kinds of names like tag names.  These names store *one* hash ID.  For a branch name, that one hash ID is, by definition, the *last* commit in the branch.
- A commit links backwards to earlier commits—not forwards, because it can't; each commit is frozen for all time once it's made.
- The *branch names* themselves *move around* over time.  The normal way for a branch name to move is forward, one step—one commit—at a time, as you make new commits.  (There are other Git commands that let you move branch names "fast" or "far", and in ways that violate the normal simple rule here.)
- This kind of `git checkout` picks out a branch name, switches *to* that branch, and gets you the files *from* the commit that's—currently, anyway—the last one on that branch.
- The special name `HEAD`, written in all uppercase, is how Git knows which *branch name* is the *current branch*.  That in turn determines which *commit* is the *current commit*.

There are lots more questions to ask (like: if a commit is a snapshot, how come `git show` shows it as a *change?*) but I'll stop here.

Answer (score 1):

No, it does not copy commits. It either

- changes the state of your working tree to some specified commit

```
git checkout <branch name or commit ref>
```

or

- brings state of some file from the state at some commit to your current working tree

```
git checkout <branch name or commit ref> <path>
```

For more details see the documentation: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout

Comment: so that means FeatureX will have exactly the commits X, Y, Z that already exist in development branch? sorry I'm noob git

Comment: @NautCouQ yes, it does not change the branch at all.